# Xamarin.Forms Background Script/Task

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to have a background script which is downloading data from ftp and then sending a push notification. I currently don't know where to start in my Xamarin.Forms Project. Can you link me some posts of examples/samples/tutorials?

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> downloading data from ftp

Please read [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49380/ftp-download-doesnt-download-correctly).

> push notification

You need read [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push).

Comment: Thanks, can you link me a post for a background script that starts when the device is booted?

Comment: Do you want to run the script when your device reboot? Maybe you want to use [Broadcast](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122868/broadcastreceiver-cant-start-service-on-boot-reboot)?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.